# How to automate a library which doesn't have any UI written in iOS platform?

Tags: android, ios, selenium, jenkins, automation

I got a project in video analytics domain. My task is to automate the library written in iOS and Android platform. I will not get any user interface to automate. All I want to do in automation is to validate the data in both platforms?.
So how it can be done?

Comment: validate the data in both platforms? how do you do this manually ?

Comment: have you looked up mobile automation using selenium? there's technologies like Selendroid for android http://selendroid.io/, as for Ios thats another story, but i hear XamarinUi is great if you are using .net. This is a poor question, you need to list the coding language you are using too, if you want any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since selenium is tagged in this question, If you just read what is selenium then probably you will understand.

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it!

That's the first line from **seleniumhq.org**

You have mentioned I will not get any user interface to automate, then Selenium can't help you.